# Parsing the URL from a file

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins

Using a log output from a jenkins URL trigger I need to parse out and store the URL that was recently changed.

```
    Polling started on 29-Jul-2014 4:19:45 PM
    Polling for the job Poller
    Looking nodes where the poll can be run.
    Looking for a candidate node to run the poll.
    Looking for a node with no predefined label.
    Trying to poll with the last built on node.

    Polling remotely on machine1
    Invoking the url: 
     http://foo.com/a/b/c/metadata.xml
    Inspecting the content
    Invoking the url: 
     http://foo.com/a/d/e/metadata.xml
    Inspecting the content
    Invoking the url: 
     http://foo.com/f/g/t/metadata.xml
    Inspecting the content
    The content of the URL has changed.

    Polling complete. Took 0.47 sec.
    Changes found. Scheduling a build.
```

I'm only interested in the URL that has been verified as changed. I'm assuming I could use 'sed' to grab the instance of saying "the content of the url has changed" but I'm not sure how I can iterate this as this type of file could change where 1 or more URLs with content could change.

I'm also very new to shell scripting..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with grep for this one:

Main Assumption: the URL is at most two lines before the 'URL has changed' line.

```
grep -B2 'URL has changed' url.txt | grep 'https\?://'
```

This does the following:

- finds the 'URL has changed' line
- prints it and the two lines before (-B2)
- from this output, grep the url (everything starting with http:// or https://)

This should exclude the other URLs.

A clean solution would be a sed match between two lines.

Comment: I figured something along those lines last night and came up with something similar        

grep -B3 "The content of the URL has changed" url.txt | awk '/http/,/xml/'